# ASP.NET Web Api System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a fully working MVC4 web site to which today I am trying to add a Web API though without success.

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[LeasingWeb.Models.Car, LeasingWeb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfCar:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LeasingWeb.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at WriteCarDBToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

My objects are these:

```
public class Image
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a car")]
    [ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Picture")]
    [Required]
    [FileExtensions(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a valid image file (.jpg, .jpeg, .gif or .png)", Extensions = ("jpg,png,jpeg"))]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Car Model")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Car Type")]
    [ForeignKey("CarType")]
    public int CarTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1,5)]
    [DisplayName("Number Of Doors")]
    public float NumDoors { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)]
    public float Acceleration { get; set; }

    public virtual CarType CarType { get; set; }
}

public class CarType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And an object that holds them both:

```
public class CarDB
{
    public IQueryable<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

The API Controller:

```
public CarDB Get(int ID = -1)
{
    CarDB car = new CarDB();
    if (ID == -1)
    {
        car = new CarDB { Cars = db.Cars.Include(c => c.CarType), Images = db.Images };
    }
    else
    {
        car = new CarDB { Cars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.ID == ID).Include(c => c.CarType), Images = db.Images.Where(c => c.CarID == ID) };
    }
    return car;
}
```

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is the Cars member on the CarDB object. The DataContractSerializer special cases collection interfaces like IEnumerable and IList, but it doesn't special case derived interfaces like IQueryable. For these interfaces, they're treated as if the type were object and any implementations must be declared as known types.

You can try fixing this by changing the `IQueryable<Car>` member to `IEnumerable<Car>`.

Comment: What reference do i need to add for [KnownType]?
The type or namespace name 'KnownTypeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: I kinda feel stupid, but i still can't get it to even accept an attribute of [KnownType], even with that reference it doesn't acknowledge this as a valid command.
(if it was just a "using" tag VS2012 would have offered it automatically)

Comment: That's weird. Make sure you have a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization, and try adding `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` and see if that helps.

Comment: That did the trick (feels stupid).  
Though i still get the error:
    <ExceptionMessage>  
    The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.  
    </ExceptionMessage>  
Added to the original message the CarType object which i forgot to show.

Comment: Could be the fact that i'm using "public virtual CarType CarType { get; set; }" be the problem?
Should I instead, try to implement this as a List<String> Type { get; set; } ?

Comment: Ok found a solution, adding this to WebApiConfig.cs under Register function:  
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =                Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
 config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
  
  
This does fix it and i'm able to get a JSON object, just want to make sure this is an Ok approach, as I am clueless in this area atm.

  
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't care about sending back XML, that is perfectly fine. JSON is WebApi's default format. Although you shouldn't even need the PreserveObjectReferences unless you have cycles in your object graph.

Comment: Missed the part that it removes XML completely. Any idea then how I can fix the XML formatter to make it export a proper xml file? seems weird as the JSON is completely fine.

Comment: when I tried changing it to this: [KnownType(typeof(DbQuery<Car>))]  
  
I get <ExceptionMessage>
Type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[LeasingWeb.Models.Car, LeasingWeb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is an invalid collection type since it does not have a valid Add method with parameter of type 'LeasingWeb.Models.Car'.
</ExceptionMessage>  
  
On the right track? or way off?

Comment: You are on the right track, but it looks like I was wrong. There's another issue here and DataContractSerializer on 4.0 can't serialize collections if they don't have an Add method which DbQuery doesn't. If you're on 4.5, I can suggest yet another way to get around that. But if you're on 4.0, I'm afraid the only thing you can do is try to change the interface on the member to IEnumerable.

Comment: I should be on the latest version, i'm thinking the main issue could be that the CAR has a virtual object referencing to CarType -> If I send CAR with a string instead -> it works.
I'll try later doing a different approach to creating the DB tables without any virtual references.

Comment: On 4.5, you should be able to use this setting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings.serializereadonlytypes.aspx along with the known type method to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with legacy code using 30 tables with about 40 Foreign Keys with Lazy Loading. I found it easier, rather than adding more annotations to all the database classes, to just create a ViewModel with the fields that I wanted to be returned.
If the data being returned is complex, then I suggest using automapper.